# Render Mathematical equations in WPF - design suggestions?

Tags: wpf

I want to display Mathematical equations in WPF. I'd like to display this using native WPF objects (i.e., NOT from previously rendered equation images). For example, variable X would be the glyph X, and so on.

What are my design options here? Is anyone aware of any library that does this? Or is DYI'ing the only way out?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this library: [Displaying math equations in WPF](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2346.aspx).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution from windowsclient is not helpfull.
It has a lot of workarounds for common problems in this field.

A much better approach is:
http://blog.noldorin.com/2010/04/rendering-tex-math-in-wpf/